# Build object name and property by variables

Tags: javascript, object

I have function with object within like this:

```
$scope.createAuction = function () {
    var auction = { auction: { langData: {} } };

    if($scope.selected.tab === $scope.infoTabs[0]) {
        auction.auction = {
            type: 'car',
            layout: $scope.selected.description
        };
        if(auction.auction.layout === 1) {
            for(var i = 0, l = $scope.langInput.values.length; i < l; i++) {
                /*
                auction.auction.langData.push({
                    $scope.langInput.values.selected: {
                        name: $scope.inputs.auction_name_account[i + 1]
                    }
                });
                */
                console.log($scope.inputs.auction_name_account[i + 1]);
                console.log($scope.langInput.values[i].selected);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(auction));
}
```

`$scope.langInput.values[i].selected` is `pl` and `eng` but user can change it and add new or delete one.
`$scope.inputs.auction_name_account[i + 1]` is description in above languages provided by user. Also if user change above languages he has to provide description in languages he had chosen.

Consoled data is good but I don't know how to build this object so after function finish job it would look like this:

```
{  
   "auction":{  
      "type":"account",
      "layout":1
      "langData":{
          "pl":{
              "name":"description in polish provided by user"
          } 
          "eng":{
              "name":"description in english provided by user"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried to build it by this code which is in `/* ... */` but it doesn't work giving me syntax error.

---

well I know that this JSON below is other then object above but it doesn't really matter I'll use JSON.stringify() later on I only have problem to bind objects to langData object.

---

**Edit**

As @Patrick Evans suggest I've change my code so I'm not longer overwriting it in code now it is:

```
$scope.createAuction = function () {
    var auction = { auction: { langData: {} } };

    if($scope.selected.tab === $scope.infoTabs[0]) {
        Object.assign(auction.auction, {
          type: 'account',
          layout: $scope.selected.description
        });
        if(auction.auction.layout === 1) {
            //alert($scope.langInput.values.length);
            for(var i = 0, l = $scope.langInput.values.length; i < l; i++) {
                auction.auction.langData.push({
                    $scope.langInput.values.selected: {
                        name: $scope.inputs.auction_name_account[i + 1]
                    }
                });
                console.log($scope.inputs.auction_name_account[i + 1]);
                console.log($scope.langInput.values[i].selected);
            }
        }
    }
    if($scope.selected.tab === $scope.infoTabs[1]) {}
    if($scope.selected.tab === $scope.infoTabs[2]) {}
    console.log(JSON.stringify(auction));
}
```

I'm still getting syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

from this line

`$scope.langInput.values.selected: {` also my IDE is highlighting it and saying

> : expected instead . given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialized `auction` like so:

```
var auction = { auction: { langData: {} } };
```

But you then later overwrite the `auction` property by doing

```
auction.auction = {
  type: 'car',
  layout: $scope.selected.description
};
```

This means there is no longer a `langData` property on `auction.auction`. You can recreate that property, or extend the `auction` property keeping any previous properties that already existed.

```
//recreate the property
auction.auction = {
  type: 'car',
  layout: $scope.selected.description,
  langData:{}
};
//or extend the property
Object.assign(auction.auction,{
  type:'car',
  layout:$scope.selected.description,
});
//or extend by explicitly setting each property
auction.auction.type = 'car';
auction.auction.layout = $scope.selected.description,
```

For actually putting data on the `langData`, it depends on what you meant for it to be.

If it is meant to be an object you can use the variable as a property accessor and set it that way

```
//if you actually meant to use $scope.langInput.values.selected
auction.auction.langData[$scope.langInput.values[i].selected] = {
  name: $scope.inputs.auction_name_account[i + 1]
};
//or if values is an array
let propName = $scope.langInput.values[i];
auction.auction.langData[propName] = {
  name: $scope.inputs.auction_name_account[i + 1]
};
```

Otherwise if it supposed to be an array, you need to change it to be an array, and then you can create your object using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```
auction.auction = {
  type: 'car',
  layout: $scope.selected.description,
  langData:[] //<-- array instead of object
};

/*...*/
auction.auction.langData.push({
  [$scope.langInput.values[i].selected]:{ //<--computed name syntax
    name:$scope.inputs.auction_name_account[i + 1]
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok that's first step to make it work but my question is about puting object to langData object and you didnt say word about it.

Comment: I've changed my code and now I'm using object.assign but what about pushing pl, eng and so on objects into auction.auction.langData ?

Comment: @BT101 I see what your other problem is will update the answer in a few with proper step

Comment: Yes you right I meant langData to be an array with objects inside, my bad but still error occur which I show in edit in question.

Comment: @BT101 Edited answer to account for langData being either an object or an array. As for the syntax errors that was from you trying to use a object / property / variable as a property name with the wrong syntax (which i show the correct usage in the edit)

Comment: Yes now it's working fine thank you. The only thing u need to add is that here `auction.auction.langData[$scope.langInput.values.selected] = {` i had to change it to `auction.auction.langData[$scope.langInput.values[i].selected] = {`. Notice `[i]` there.